# ui-router deepstateredirect params

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-router-extras

I'm wondering is there any way to specify deepStateRedirect parameter from ajax call ? For example to load from data using resolve and pass parameter to deepStateRedirect in case of user came to this state without parameter? So it is come kind of default parameter which is not constant for all cases.

for example:

```
var states = [];
//
states.push({
   name:'app.state1',
   url:'/state1',
   templateUrl:'state1.html',
   resolve:{
      data:function(SomeService){
         return SomeService.getData();
      }
   },
   deepStateRedirect:{
      default:{
         state:'app.state1.subState',
         params:{
            param1: data.property1
         }
      },
      params:true
   }
})

states.push({
   name:'app.state1.subState',
   url:'/subState/{param1}',
   templateUrl:'subState.html'
})
```

**Update:**
I know that I can apply that logic part in state1 controller and check if param1 is empty or not to load that param value with ajax call. But in that case if I will use $state.go() then after pressing back button in browser will go back to state1 and not to state where from I navigated to state1